# Empty Result When Merging DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I would like to merge `patient_df`:

```
id    first_name      last_name      birthdate
1           John            Doe     2001-12-21
2          David          Xavier    1999-11-24
```

With this `contact_df` (based on columns `{birthdate,first_name,last_name}`):

```
first_name      last_name      birthdate      city      Postal   
     David          Xavier    1999-11-24   Buffalo      P9B3R3
      John            Doe     2001-12-21    Irvine      V4A3E2
```

Types of columns are all `object`, except `id` is `int64`

It returns empty when I tried this

```
df_merged = pd.merge(patient_df, contact_df, how='inner', on=['birthdate','first_name','last_name'])
```

The result is:

```
Empty DataFrame
Column: [id, first_name, last_name, birthdate, city, postal]
Index: []
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't post images. Take a tour of [how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, I fixed it.

Comment: great, now its better.

Comment: I guess your keys are not matching between two dataframes, check for any whitespace in names.

Comment: The names format are identical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use merge correctly, you should try this line of code:

```
patient_df.merge(contact_df, how='inner', on=['birthdate','first_name','last_name'])
```

Hope it works correctly now!

Cheers,
T